# Changing a registry key's permissions from Chef

Tags: windows-server-2008, chef, windows-registry

I'm attempting to automate the Jenkins Windows slave installation and I need to change the owner and permission of some keys in order to allow read/write access to certain keys for the administrator user. See [Jenkins docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windows+slaves+fail+to+start+via+DCOM#WindowsslavesfailtostartviaDCOM-Windows64bitinstallationrelatedissues) for details.

I have found the [registry_key](https://docs.chef.io/resource_registry_key.html) resource but this does not mention how to adjust the actual permissions of registry keys. I don't need to create/read/update or delete keys - just adjust the permissions.

Is there a way to do this from within Chef? Or, if not, is there a way to do this via a Powershell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll outline the expedient solution in order to get some closure here but it ideally needs to be refactored to use the [Chef DSC Resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_dsc_resource.html) since this can manage the more esoteric Windows features. Thanks to [@coderanger](https://github.com/coderanger) for that tip.

What I ended up doing was using the [SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/) utility from within an execute block as follows

**Set entry owner**

```
execute 'update registry entry owner' do
  command 'c:/path/to/SetACL.exe -on "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}" -ot reg -actn setowner -ownr n:Administrators'
end
```

**Set entry permissions**

```
execute 'update registry permissions' do
  command 'c:/path/to/SetACL.exe -on "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}" -ot reg -actn ace -ace "n:Administrators;p:full'
end
```

this is for setting the [Jenkins Windows Slave](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windows+slaves+fail+to+start+via+DCOM#WindowsslavesfailtostartviaDCOM-Windows64bitinstallationrelatedissues) registry entries to allow remote installation and management of the Jenkins slave service.